# Azure function: Azure Functions Core Tools and Zip Deployment confusion

Tags: azure, azure-functions

There are a lot of documentations but one really has to dive deep and spend hours sorting things out...

It is a simple question: when it comes to deploying project files to Azure function, we have:

Zip deployment:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip
```

and `Azure Functions Core Tools`:

```
func azure functionapp publish
```

I know that `Azure Functions Core Tools` is essentially running Zip Deployment under the hood, but why are there two commands?

Is the `func azure functionapp publish` command actually calling the `az functionapp deployment source...` command?

Comment: Zip deployment is a deployment method that uses the .zip file deployment facilities of the Kudu deployment service to publish  Azure Functions. we can deploy your function app project files directly from a .zip file using the az functionapp deployment

Comment: Azure Functions Core Tools is a command-line interface for creating, developing, and deploying Azure Functions. It provides a publish command, func azure functionapp publish, which is essentially running Zip Deployment .

Answer (score 1):

Zip deployment is a deployment method that uses the .zip file deployment facilities of the Kudu deployment service to publish  Azure Functions. we can deploy your function app project files directly from a .zip file using the az functionapp deployment source config-zip [command](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push.md).

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <YourResourceGroup> --name <YourFunctionAppName> --src functionapp.zip
```

[image]

```
func azure functionapp publish <YourFunctionAppName>
```

[image]

Azure Functions Core Tools is a command-line interface for creating, developing, and deploying Azure Functions. It provides a publish command, func azure functionapp publish, which is essentially running Zip Deployment .

- The func azure functionapp publish command is not actually calling the az functionapp deployment source config-zip command, but it is using the same deployment APIs when publishing a local project to Azure

So, `func azure functionapp publish` is a higher-level command that encapsulates the ZIP deployment process, making it easier for developers, while `az functionapp deployment source config-zip` is a lower-level Azure CLI command for configuring the deployment source.